# objective c - Xcode long int display with formatting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, long-integer, nsnumberformatter

I’m having issues with this when the numbers are large.  For example if the number is  3670000000,  I want the label to be 3,670,000,000. When the numbers are large it gives me a value of 2,147,483,657.  I’m sure it must be a variable length issue. I tried using long long int for numC.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
int numC;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *valuestring= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[values objectAtIndex:indexA] objectForKey:@"hits"]];
numC=[valuestring intValue];


NSString *results = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:numC]];    
label1.text =results;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` type cannot hold a value greater than 2,147,483,657. You could use an unsigned int and the maximum value would be 4,294,967,295. Look [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Data_Types#int_Data_Type) for more information. You could try this too to extend the range of the data type:

```
long long int numC;

//Number formatter and string operations

numC = [valuestring longLongValue];

NSString *results = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong: numC]];    
label1.text = results;
```

Additionally, if none of the values you are retrieving contain a negative value, you could make it an `unsigned long long int`. In that case, make your code this:

```
unsigned long long int numC;

//Number formatter and string operations

numC = [valuestring longLongValue];

NSString *results = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong: numC]];    
label1.text = results;
```

Also make sure that in this line...

```
 NSString *valuestring= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[values objectAtIndex:indexA] objectForKey:@"hits"]];
```

...the value you are retrieving is a `long long int`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is also the C++ class for `bigInteger` if you really need to do operations with numbers larger than allowed by `int`. If you don't need to do many operations, store the number as a NSString. Then to work with it just take the end of the string, convert it to an `int`, do your operations, then put the number back into the string.

Comment: I just want to compare which is bigger.  I think I’ll just go with the long long int and if its larger I’ll work it differently.

Comment: Sure. Although for comparison, you really only need to start at the beginning of the number string (highest value end) and iterate down until you find a difference. Then, whichever number is higher belongs to the larger number.